# Airflow Jinja Template Not Working with Custom Operators

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to make custom Airflow operators like the following:

```py
class NewCheckOperator(BaseOperator):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'NewCheckOperator'
    }
    template_fields = ('sql1', 'sql2')  # type: Iterable[str]
    template_ext = ('.hql', '.sql',)  # type: Iterable[str]
    ui_color = '#91E6F2'

    ratio_formulas = {
        'max_over_min': lambda cur, ref: float(max(cur, ref)) / min(cur, ref),
        'relative_diff': lambda cur, ref: float(abs(cur - ref)) / ref,
    }

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        table: str,
        template_time: str,
        metrics_thresholds: Dict[str, int],
        random_param: int, 
        ratio_formula: Optional[str] = 'max_over_min',
        ignore_zero: Optional[bool] = True,
        conn_id: Optional[str] = None,
        *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #some logic here 

        self.sql1 = " '{{ ds }}' "
        self.sql2 = "'{{ macros.ds_add(ds, " + str(self.random_param) + ") }}'"

    def execute(self, context=None):
        hook = self.get_db_hook()
        self.log.info('Using ratio formula: %s', self.ratio_formula)
        self.log.info('Executing SQL check: %s', self.sql2)
        row2 = hook.get_first(self.sql2)
        self.log.info('Executing SQL check: %s', self.sql1)
        row1 = hook.get_first(self.sql1)

        if not row2:
            raise AirflowException("The query {} returned None".format(self.sql2))
        if not row1:
            raise AirflowException("The query {} returned None".format(self.sql1))

       #other logic 

    def get_db_hook(self):
        return BaseHook.get_hook(conn_id=self.conn_id)

class BigQueryNewCheckOperator(NewCheckOperator): 
    template_fields = ('table', 'gcp_conn_id', )

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 table: str,
                 metrics_thresholds: dict,
                 random_param: int,
                 date_filter_column: str = 'ds',                 
                 gcp_conn_id: str = 'google_cloud_default',
                 bigquery_conn_id: Optional[str] = None,
                 use_legacy_sql: bool = True,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            table=table, metrics_thresholds=metrics_thresholds,
            date_filter_column=date_filter_column, days_back=days_back,
            *args, **kwargs)

        if bigquery_conn_id:
            warnings.warn(
                "The bigquery_conn_id parameter has been deprecated. You should pass "
                "the gcp_conn_id parameter.", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=3)
            gcp_conn_id = bigquery_conn_id

        self.gcp_conn_id = gcp_conn_id
        self.use_legacy_sql = use_legacy_sql

    def get_db_hook(self):
        return BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
                            use_legacy_sql=self.use_legacy_sql)
```

but for some reason the templating in the `NewCheckOperator` is not working (by this I mean that they are treated as `str` literals like `" '{{ ds }}' "`), despite explicitly setting `sql1` and `sql2` as `template_fields`. This is closely modelled after the `IntervalCheckOperator` and `BigQueryIntervalCheckOperator` so I am not sure why the airflow macros are not working. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the following:

```py
self.sql1 = " '{{ ds }}' "
self.sql2 = "'{{ macros.ds_add(ds, " + str(self.random_param) + ") }}'"
```

You should only use these macros from within a JINJA template or you can pass these macros through into the Operator as a parameter from the DAG.

There is probably some decorator/wrapper around the Operator that takes your templated fields and renders them before your Operator is entered. You're essentially taking the rendered parameters and then changing them to literal strings.

Comment: The `IntervalCheckOperator` has the exact same line, found [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fd124a54b9261db136aa95b67d0d56599da9fe52/airflow/operators/check_operator.py#L277). Are they doing something differently that I am not aware of?

Comment: Good point - how are you calling the DAG? are you doing it manually or are you letting it fire automatically on the schedule?

Comment: I have it scheduled as `@once`, and at every iteration/code change I clear the failed tasks to try again.

Comment: @SimonD I have a similar issue of `execution_date` not being resolved in jinja template. does it have something to do with the DAG's way of execution? I clear the dagrun for rerunning, apparently similar to @manesioz